# iOS wifi options with built in VPN

Tags: wifi, security, vpn, ios

When connecting to wifi on iOS via the settings application there are some wifi networks listed that have a second line that says something like “protected by CyberGhost”, does that mean that the wifi option has a VPN built into it? If so does that mean the connection between the iOS device and the router will be encrypted? Or is it just a VPN from the access point onwards towards the internet?

Comment: Please add a screenshot so we can see what you see :-)

Comment: I’ll try to add a screenshot when I’m near an example again but I’m mostly in a rural area without examples.

Comment: Do you have a CyberGhost VPN app installed on your device??

Comment: No this is usually in coffee shops or public wifi locations, some residential areas